# React-Intl how to switch locale and messages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, create-react-app, react-intl

I'm new to reactJS and using multi-language support.I would like to get the

> locale variable from Header drop-down(By default - 'English' if user selects 'Spanish'.I would like to re-render the entire site content to be Spanish.I have messages configured for English/Spanish where you'll see that in import. I've confused where to get dynamic Locale variable. Also I'm not using redux/flux architecture.

Code below

### index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import {addLocaleData,IntlProvider } from "react-intl";
import en from "react-intl/locale-data/en";
import es from "react-intl/locale-data/es";
import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";


import messages from "./components/messages/messages"
import {flattenMessages} from "./components/utils/utils";

addLocaleData([...en,...es]);
let locale = (navigator.languages && navigator.languages[0])
              || navigator.language
              || navigator.userLanguage
              || 'en-us';

ReactDOM.render(
    <IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={flattenMessages(messages[locale])}>
      <App />
    </IntlProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

### header.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Navbar, Nav, NavItem, MenuItem, NavDropdown} from "react-bootstrap";
import {IndexLinkContainer} from "react-router-bootstrap";
import {Icon,Image,Dropdown} from "semantic-ui-react";
import injectTapEventPlugin from "react-tap-event-plugin";
import Auth from "../modules/Auth";
import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom";
import AuthService from "../service/AuthService";
import Logo from "../../Assets/images/instapassLogo.png"
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import {FormattedMessage} from 'react-intl';


let languageOptions = [ { key: 'en-us', text: 'English', value: 'en-us' }, { key: 'en-es', text: 'Español', value: 'en-es' }];
/* Define your default translations */
let i18nConfig = {
    locale: 'en-us'
};
class Header extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        injectTapEventPlugin();
        this.state = { show: false,  redirect:false,user: Auth.getUser(),uri:null};
        this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
        this.setLanguage = this.setLanguage.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let userObj = JSON.parse(Auth.getToken());
        const self = this;
        if(userObj !== null){
            AuthService.viewProfile(userObj.token).then(function(response){
                self.setState({
                    uri: response.uri,
                });
            }).catch(function (error) {
                alert(error);
            });
        }
    }


    onChangeLanguage =(e, { value }) => {
        this.setState({ locale: value });
        i18nConfig.locale = this.state.locale;
    };

    logout = () => {
        const self = this;

        const location = {
            pathname: '/',
            state: { from: {pathname: '/'} }
        };
        Auth.deauthenticateUser();
        self.setState({ redirect: true});
        // change the current URL to /
        self.props.history.replace(location);
    };

    render() {
        let user = Auth.getUser() && JSON.parse(Auth.getUser());
        let uri = this.state.uri;
        const { from }  = { from: { pathname: '/' }};
        const { redirect } = this.state;
        if (redirect) {
            return (
                <Redirect to={from}/>
            )
        }
        return (
            <IntlProvider key={ i18nConfig.locale } locale={ i18nConfig.locale } {flattenMessages(messages[locale])}>
             <Navbar collapseOnSelect fixedTop fluid>
                <Navbar.Header>
                    <Link to="/">
                        <Navbar.Brand>
                            <img src={Logo} alt="logo" style={{width: 164, height: 50}}
                                 className="img-responsive"/>
                        </Navbar.Brand>
                    </Link>
                    <Navbar.Toggle/>
                </Navbar.Header>
                <Navbar.Collapse>
                    <Nav>
                        <IndexLinkContainer to="/">
                            <NavItem eventKey={1}>
                                <span className="navItem">
                                   <FormattedMessage id="menu.home"/>
                                </span>
                            </NavItem>
                        </IndexLinkContainer>
                        {Auth.isUserAuthenticated() ? (
                        <IndexLinkContainer to="/profile">
                            <NavItem eventKey={2}>
                                <span className="navItem">
                                    <FormattedMessage id="menu.profile"/>
                                </span>
                            </NavItem>
                        </IndexLinkContainer>) : ''}
                        <IndexLinkContainer to="/location">
                            <NavItem eventKey={3}>
                                <span className="navItem">
                                    <FormattedMessage id="menu.locations"/>
                                </span>
                            </NavItem>
                        </IndexLinkContainer>
                        <IndexLinkContainer to="/wallet">
                            <NavItem eventKey={4}>
                                <span className="navItem">
                                    <FormattedMessage id="menu.wallet"/>
                                </span>
                            </NavItem>
                        </IndexLinkContainer>
                        {Auth.isUserAuthenticated() ? (
                        <IndexLinkContainer to="/ticket">
                            <NavItem eventKey={5}>
                                <span className="navItem">
                                    <FormattedMessage id="menu.myTickets"/>
                                </span>
                            </NavItem>
                        </IndexLinkContainer>) : ''}
                        {/*<IndexLinkContainer to="/favorites">*/}
                            {/*<NavItem eventKey={6}>*/}
                                {/*<span className="navItem">
                                <FormattedMessage id="menu.favorites"/>
                                </span>*/}
                            {/*</NavItem>*/}
                        {/*</IndexLinkContainer>*/}
                        <IndexLinkContainer to="/help">
                            <NavItem eventKey={7}>
                                <span className="navItem">
                                    <FormattedMessage id="menu.help"/>
                                </span>
                            </NavItem>
                        </IndexLinkContainer>
                        <IndexLinkContainer to="/contact">
                            <NavItem eventKey={8}>
                                <span className="navItem">
                                    <FormattedMessage id="menu.contactUs"/>
                                </span>
                            </NavItem>
                        </IndexLinkContainer>
                        <IndexLinkContainer to="/terms">
                            <NavItem eventKey={9}>
                                <span className="navItem">
                                    <FormattedMessage id="menu.terms"/>
                                </span>
                            </NavItem>
                        </IndexLinkContainer>
                    </Nav>
                    <Nav pullRight>
                        <NavItem>
                            <Dropdown floating inline options={languageOptions} defaultValue='en-us' onChange={this.onChangeLanguage}/>
                        </NavItem>
                    </Nav>
                    <Nav pullRight>
                        <NavDropdown eventKey={10}
                                     title={
                                         <div className="pull-left">
                                             {
                                                 user ?
                                                 (<span className="mui--bg-color-black">
                                                     { uri ?  <Image src={uri} avatar /> :<Icon name='user'/>}
                                                     <FormattedMessage id="auth.hello"/> &nbsp;{user && user.firstName}
                                             </span>) :
                                                 <span className="mui--bg-color-black"><Icon name='user'/>
                                                     <FormattedMessage id="auth.hello"/>
                                                 </span>
                                             }

                                         </div>
                                     }
                                     id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                            {Auth.isUserAuthenticated() ? (
                                <span className="mui--text-center">
                                        <MenuItem eventKey={13} href="/profile"><Icon name='setting'/>
                                            <b><FormattedMessage id="auth.account"/></b></MenuItem>
                                        <MenuItem divider/>
                                        <MenuItem eventKey={12} href="/" onClick={() => this.logout()}>
                                            <Icon name='sign out'/>
                                            <b>
                                                 <FormattedMessage id="auth.signOut"/>
                                            </b>
                                        </MenuItem>
                                    </span>
                            ) : (
                                <span className="mui--text-center">
                                        <MenuItem eventKey={11} href="/signup">
                                            <b>
                                             <FormattedMessage id="auth.register"/>
                                           </b>
                                        </MenuItem>
                                        <MenuItem divider/>
                                        <MenuItem eventKey={14} href="/login">
                                            <b>  <FormattedMessage id="auth.signIn"/></b>
                                        </MenuItem>
                                    </span>
                            )}
                        </NavDropdown>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>

        );
    }
}
export default Header;
```

Could you please provide some tips how I can re-endered the entire site content by changing the Language dropdown to "Spanish" or vice-versa.(I'm not using redux/flux).

Comment: Is it not working? What is the error? There is a lot of code here and it is hard to know what to focus on?

Comment: @Phil yes, it's not working.All changes related localization in Index.js.Since, I have drop-down in Header.js, not sure how to pass it to index.js which will reload the entire the site content. If you look at index.js **messages[locale])**, locale is browser based and I need to be dynamic by choosing dropdown in header.

Comment: I have fixed it. post your comments if anyone need assistance.

Comment: @NetonGlobal How did you solve it? How does the complete application know that the language has changed? In your code example, only the header component knows that the language has changed.

Comment: I did change the App.js that would receive props from Header.js component which will change the entire site content like a charm.